# Shorthand for functions to map

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

In a `map`, I can call a method on the passed-in value using the convenient `&:` notation:

```
nums = (0..10).to_a
strs = nums.map(&:to_s)
```

Is there something similar for calling a function with the value passed in as the first argument?

```
nums = (0..10).to_a
nums.each(puts) # error!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this:

```
nums.each(&method(:puts))
```

but actually it's not much shorter :)

Comment: But it saves you from having to invent a readable, communicative, semantic, concise, intention-revealing, expressive name for a variable that shouldn't exist in the first place. (Or just give up and use `i` :-) )

Comment: In most cases it's as easy as a singular form of the enumerable var name, but in cases when it's not I agree it's a pain.

Comment: `puts nums` does the same thing :-)

Answer (score 11):

Disclaimer: This post is purely educational. `nums.each {|n| puts n}` is really the only reasonable thing to write in a real project.

### Understanding `nums.map(&:to_s)`

The existing short form works very simply. `&` calls `to_proc` on the symbol, and `to_proc` on a symbol is defined like this.

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |*args| args.shift.__send__(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

Since this proc will start acting like a regular block that is passed into map, the `*args` in this case is really each element we're iterating through. We take the first of args (since `*` turns arguments into an array), and send `self` to it, `self` being the actual symbol, such as `:to_s`. Remaining arguments are passed in. So it's like saying `nums.map{ |*args| args.shift.__send__(:to_s, *args) }`.

### Changing it to enable `nums.each(&:puts)`

We could easily re-implement `to_proc` to act differently. Here's a quick example.

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |*args| __send__(self, *args) }
  end
end

(1..10).each(&:print) # => 12345678910
```

Here instead of sending symbol name as a message to the element, we are just calling symbol as a method on the current context, and simply passing the iterated element as an argument to it.

So it's more like saying `(1..10).each{|*args| __send__(:print, *args)}`.

### Understanding `nums.each(&method(:puts))`

That said, as nash pointed out you could call `nums.each(&method(:puts))`. What happens there is that you get an object that represents method `puts` using ruby's `method` method. So then `&` calls `.to_proc` on the method object, turning it into proc, which itself starts playing the role of the block passed into `each` (or `map`). The arguments passed into that proc (each element you're iterating) then become the arguments to that method. Neat.

### Implementing `xargs`

In order to avoid overwriting standard behavior, we could hypothetically implement our own xargs feature, like in shell scripting. (Do not do this at home, too-clever is bad.)

```
class Symbol
  def to_xargs
    Proc.new{ |*args| __send__(self, *args) }
  end
end

def xargs(sym)
  sym.to_xargs
end

(1..10).each(&xargs(:print)) # prints 12345678910
```

Comment: Very neat! I wouldn't use this but I'm glad to know that I could.

Comment: Updated with fixes and explanation of Nash's answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use it? One of the biggest advantages of Ruby is that you have incredible flexibility to "mold" the language to your purposes, making it more powerful and concise. Whether you use it or not, you pay for that flexibility in every Ruby program you write, in the form of slower execution speed than would be attainable if the language was less dynamic. I have felt the need for something like `xargs` many times, and hope to see something added to Ruby to make it just as concise as the `&:symbol` notation.

Comment: @AlexD "One of the biggest advantages of Ruby is that you have incredible flexibility to "mold" the language to your purposes" - that's also one of the disadvantages. Ruby gives you power to build great DSLs for your domain, but when you decide to mess with ruby's core (such as adding a method to `Symbol`), you have to tread carefully. Of course adding this feature to the language is a whole another topic. :)

Comment: @AlexD whatever gave you that idea? No clue what that means. :) P.S. Ah must've been my nickname. Someone said in the past it means something in japanese.

Comment: If an operation is so generally useful that it makes sense it *should* be in the core (although the developers of Ruby haven't done so yet), I say go ahead and add it yourself. Redefining existing operations has greater potential for confusion than adding completely new ones; if a reader sees you calling a method on a core class which isn't built-in, they will know you must have defined it yourself and go looking for the definition.

Comment: Your nick means "white person" in Japanese. The concern about extending the language is that the code will become hard to read, but especially in large, complex programs, it can make the program *easier* to read, simply because it becomes so much shorter. Paul Graham put this very well in the classic *On Lisp* (I'd have to dig it up to get the exact quote).

Comment: @AlexD Worst is when it gets added to the language using the same method, but working slightly differently. Again, not saying it's taboo, just be careful how you extend core.

Comment: Agreed. That's the same point I just made: "Redefining existing operations has greater potential for confusion than adding completely new ones".

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely similar but how about:

```
nums.each {|n| puts n}
```

Comment: Right, that's the verbose way to do it. I could call a method on the value using `nums.each {|n| n.to_s}`. I'm wondering if there's something shorter.

Comment: I contend that my solution is more ruby-idiomatic :) but hey, both solutions are valid and quite interesting. Always glad to learn something new about Ruby.

Comment: "more ruby-idiomatic", plus faster. The other way relies on a longer path to accomplish the same functionality.

Comment: It is more idiomatic, but it requires inventing a name for a variable. Names are "expensive": they should be expressive, they should communicate intent, therefore you need to think long and hard about what a good name would be. This is what I mean by "expensive". If you spend the cost for a name, you elevate the variable to a certain level of importance, which, I would argue, this particular variable doesn't have. Therefore, by writing in point-free style, you can avoid inventing names for things that really shouldn't have a name in the first place.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've always thought of curly-brace blocks as "one-time" and thus the use I propose has always felt natural and correct, true you need to use a variable but I think semantically everybody knows this is a 'use and discard' variable and the code should be short and sweet enough that the "level of importance" of which you speak is a non-issue. If you need something longer, use the do...end block syntax, and in that case, yes, be careful in choosing your variable names. You make an interesting point though, I'll be sure to consider that when coding / giving advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) receives an array, it prints each element in a new line...

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record
>   separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with
>   a newline sequence. **If called with an array argument, writes each
>   element on a new line**. If called without arguments, outputs a single
>   record separator.

So...

```
puts nums
```